# c# draw (connection) lines without crossing any other line

Tags: algorithm, drawing, lines

I got a small problem with making a connection display. It has to be dynamic so i can't use paint :P.
Lets say i have some connectors at the left side and some other at the right side, how can i draw lines between them without crossing any other lines.

note:
its possible to got more then 2 lines of connectors like:

```
┌---------------------------┐
| o------------o            o
└-o            o            o
  o            o            o
  o            o            o
```

somebody got any ideas?
thnx!

stefan

Comment: How is this a C# problem? I think you're looking for an algorithm here.

Comment: Sorry you are right, but i didn't think of an algorithm. because im busy with c# i used it. edited >:).

Answer (score 3):

that is only possible if your connection network shows a planar graph

maybe this will help you: http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/papers/gd-tutorial/gd-constraints.pdf

Comment: Love the PDF, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to be disappointed - in the general case this is impossible to do even with two lines of connectors, for example:

```
┌────────────────┐
│ o*           o─┘
|              |
| o────────────o
| |
└─o            o*
```

*(Updated in response to comment)*

How do you then connect the two connectors marked with a `*` without crossing over any existing lines?

Just come up with a way to represent lines that cross without intersecting.

Comment: If there is some space between the rows in your example, it could still work ^^.

Comment: sorry i didnt tell you but such situations i dont get :). only the more 'simple' situations like i discribed.

Comment: @Noio Fine :-p, but it is still impossible in the general case - my maths is too rusty to be able to properly explain why though.

Comment: @StefanKoenen What situations don't you get?  In that case you need to be a lot more specific in your question.